# Deleting range of data in a file

Tags: linux

I am trying to delete a range of data inside of a file using linux bash script.

file:

```
1. [/]
2. 
3. [A:/]
4. Test1 = rw
5. Test2 = r
6. * = 
7.
8. [B:/]
9. Test3 = r
```

I am trying to delete lines 3-7. Ive looked at using grep which returns instances of the search criteria ([) and line numbers but it returns in a long string. then I would try to split the string and get the relevant data to delete.

I will know the data on line 3 but I wont know what the next item in brackets is, Therefore the search is needed to find the section.

Can anyone thing of a better way of doing this as I believe my method would take alot longer and lots of code to implement?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk, if you know the numbers:

```
$ awk 'NR<3 || NR>7' a
1. [/]
2. 
8. [B:/]
9. Test3 = r
```

Otherwise, use this to skip the lines between `[A]` (inclusive) and `[B]` (not inclusive):

```
$ awk '/[A]/ {f=1} /[B]/ {f=0} !f' a
1. [/]
2. 
8. [B:/]
9. Test3 = r
```

This sets a flag `f` when `[A]` is found, and unsets when `[B]` is found. Then, `!f` condition is true just when the flag is not set. As awk's default behaviour on a true condition is to print the line, it prints lines when the flag is not set.

---

### Update

> Yeah, im after from line 3 to the line before the next square brackets

```
$ awk '{if (f==1 && $0 ~ /\[/) f=0} NR==3 {f=1} !f' file
1. [/]
2. 
8. [B:/]
9. Test3 = r
```

Comment: I wont know the line numbers, and i wont know what 'B' is, it could be anything but i know the line would start with open square brackets

Comment: Your sample input has three lines with square brackets. What is the pattern of the block you want to skip? From line 3 to next open bracket? It is important to know what algorithm you want to implement before starting to write any line of code.

Comment: Yeah, im after from line 3 to the line before the next square brackets

Comment: @NoLiver92 let me know if it worked to you. If so, remember you can accept the answer.